# I believe the example in §7.3.1.2/1 is incorrect

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, language-lawyer

§7.3.1.2/1

> Members (including explicit specializations of templates (14.7.3)) of
> a namespace can be defined within that namespace. [ Example:
>
> ```
> namespace X {
>     void f() { / ... / }
> }
> ```

In order to define a function in a namespace you've got to use one of the specifiers: `static` or `inline`. Am I correct?

Comment: how about functions defined in a cpp file ?

Comment: Even in a header, the language requirement is ODR, not one of those keywords.

Comment: OP, you seem to be confusing "defined in a namespace" (which is a property of the C++ language and is what the example correctly demonstrates) with "defined in a header" (which is just a matter of code organisation and the compiler generally doesn't care whether a definition is in a header or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can define it within a namespace with non-inline external linkage, as long as there's only one definition in the program (to meet the requirements of the One Definition Rule).

Generally, this means you can define it like that within a source file (so that it's only defined once, in a single translation unit), but must declare it `inline` (or possibly `static`, or in an unnamed namespace, in unusual circumstances) if you define it in a header, which might be included by more than one translation unit. But this has nothing to do with whether or not the definition is inside its namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You can imagine you have a header file with declaration:

```
namespace X {
    void f();
}
```

And translation unit, including this header, with following content:

```
namespace X {
    void f() { / ... / }
}
```

as an alternative to:

```
void X::f() { / ... / }
```

Or a translation unit that includes nothing related to `X::f`, that both declares and defines the function:

```
namespace X {
    void f() { / ... / }
}
```

Comment: After thinking about this a bit more, I decided to accept the answer by Mike Seymour. His answer gave me a better description on how to read and understand §7.3.1.2/1.

Answer (score 2):

Even without a header, you can have a .cpp file containing:

```
namespace X {
    void f() { / ... / }
}
```

Or you can have it in a header if it's included to only one translation unit

Also, even if header is included in multiple translation units, it can be like this:

```
namespace {
    namespace X {
        void f() { / ... / }
    }
}
```